# Octopress and flexibility: creating and previewing posts online?

Tags: blogs, octopress, github-pages

So I was considering making a blog with Wordpress or Blogger, but then I discovered Octopress, which seems very nice, and would surely give me a better impression of being in control of my blog.

However, I'm concerned with flexibility. In Wordpress I can create or edit a post from wherever I want (my phone, a friend's computer or a device running on Windows), and I can save drafts and see previews online.

On the other hand, it seems that for Octopress I need a well-configured Unix system with git and ruby, and it needs to have a local clone of the repository, etc. Do you think there is a way around this?

I saw github pages can automatically generate pages from the markdown, but it doesn't seem to work with Octopress: I tried directly creating a post in the `_post` folder of the `source` branch on my github.io repo, but it was not taken into account and not added to the blog. I had to go back to my local setup, `git pull`, `rake generate` and `rake deploy`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need a configured machine with Ruby, Python and git.  That's why they call it a hackers' blogging platform.  :-)

Some people have taken it a little further and setup a C.I. server on a cheap VM online (Continuous Integration server) to monitor github for changes (or wait for callbacks, which is the preferred method).  If you don't know what or how a C.I. server works, they are very nessasary for development.

The point is, people setup a C.I. server for Octopress that auto-deploys a new version to your live site as soon as there is a change committed to git.

E.g. you edit or create a new `_posts/2014-05-16-my-remote-post.markdown` file directly from GitHub and write your post.  Don't forget the YAML at the top or it will ignored (tip: use published: false until you are ready for it to show up in the sitemap and paging links).

I've seen posts of people using Travis C.I. server for that.  Try googling for 'octopress Travis'.

As for remote blogging, you are going to have with GitHub and thinking you can do this on ur mobile browser (and there's no decent app for GitHub to edit source files).  The problem with GitHub is that the mobile version won't let you switch branches!  A simple but stupid thing.

Personally, I use a great markdown editor on my Android Called Writeily.  It is a beautiful font and clean UI.  I just wish they had a Dropbox or Google Drive sync feature.  I usually write, or mostly start an idea, and group them up and send them to me in email.

When I am ready to finish the posts (looking up YouTube URLs, references, previewing the look, etc) then I'll `rake deploy` from my laptop or desktop or a Linux VM I have on a portable stick.

I never have a complete post ready to publish directly from my mobile.  Maybe it is because I am not perfect, maybe it is because the {% %} is too freaking awkward to type over and over again, maybe cause writing source code on a module device is so fustrationg,  and so on that I always use something with a better keyboard.  And when I am using those machines, I have everything I need for `rake preview` to work.

BTW, `rake preview` is what you use locally to preview your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I successfully set up Travis to build the posts I edit on prose.io :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rake to generate new posts and pages. Use `rake new_post['name-of-post']` to generate a new post and `rake new_page['name-of-page']` to generate a new page. You need to use it this way so that the ruby knows that you have new posts and pages. And don't forget to update your navigation in `custom/navigation.html`!